# Enumerate with arabic numbers and letters

Tags: enumitem

I'm trying to get the following structure:

[image]

(Items with arabic numbers, sub-items with letters)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf8
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm, start=0]

\item hello
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*, leftmargin=0cm]

\item this is 0.A without indentation.
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Problem**

I can't get the 0.A, 0.B and so on working.

Comment: Use `label*` instead of `label` on the 2nd `enumerate`.  More specifically, `[label*=\Alph*., leftmargin=0cm]`.  You can tweak the `leftmargin` value to get the desired indent on the 2nd level.

Comment: perfect, @StevenB.Segletes. Now, as I wrote left margin zero they are misaligned, any help?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes so just modifying leftmargin value manually until they are aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `label*` instead of label on the 2nd enumerate. More specifically, `[label*=\Alph*., leftmargin=0cm]`. You can tweak the `leftmargin` value to get the desired indent on the 2nd level.

Note that labels are right-aligned in such environments.  Thus, since `A` is wider than `B`, the left side of your alpha labels will not be *exactly* aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf8
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm, start=0]

\item hello

\item next item
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\Alph*., leftmargin=.36cm]

\item this is 1.A without indentation.


\item this is 1.B without indentation.
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: .36 was set just comparing pdf output or how do you set it?

Comment: @santimirandarp I did it also with trial and error, but note the warning I added: labels are right aligned and not all alpha chars are the same width.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with the `wide=0pt` option of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, spanish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, labelsep=0pt}
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\llap{\makebox[2.2em][l]{\arabic*.}}, ref=\arabic*, start=0]

\item hello
\begin{enumerate} [label=\llap{\makebox[2.2em][l]{\arabic{enumi}.\Alph*.}}]

\item this is 0.A without indentation.

\item this is 0.B without indentation.
\end{enumerate}

\item next item
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\llap{\makebox[2.2em][l]{\arabic{enumi}.\Alph*.}}]

\item this is 1.A without indentation.

\item this is 1.B without indentation.
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\renewcommand{}` to define the desired label format `enumii` (the `subitem` of `enumi`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf8
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\Alph{enumii}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm, start=0]     
\item Fecha de presentaci\'on: 6/06/2018
\item Datos Institucioinales
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Instituci\`on \\
        ISFD N3
        \item Dependencias ... \\
            ISFD ...
        \item Instituuciones ...
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the margin issue, and since the OP is using `enumitem` then using `\label*` is the appropriate way to do this as in Steven's answer.